# (Mac) How do I STOP Netbeans from automatically SELECTING a suggested keyword, BUT keep the POPUP open for me to select MANUALLY?

Tags: macos, netbeans, autocomplete, manual

How can I stop Netbeans from automatically completing my code, but keeping the popup open so that I can select from its list?
Thanks for the read. :D

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the Completion Selectors.
That seems to do the trick.